# Powershell function parameter type System.ConsoleColor - Missing ')' in function parameter list

Tags: .net, function, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to create a cmdlet function in powershell with 2 arguments. I want one of those 2  arguments to be a [ConsoleColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor?view=netframework-4.7.2) but ISE complains and says there is a *Missing ')' in function parameter list.* But I can't find this missing `)`.

Here is my function:

```bsh
function Log {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [string[]]$messages,

        # If I remove the following parameter, everything works fine
        [System.ConsoleColor]$color = Default # ISE Complains here before `=`
    )

    if (($messages -eq $null) -or ($messages.Length -eq 0)) {
        $messages = @("")
    }

    foreach ($msg in $messages) {
        Write-Host $msg -ForegroundColor $color
        $msg | Out-File $logFile -Append
    }
}
```

I'm not very good in powershell so it might be something stupid that I just don't know yet.

Comment: What is the Default being assigned to $color in this context? It does not appears to be valid System.ConsoleColor identifier so I'm interest in where it is coming from.

Comment: `default` is a PowerShell language keyword that's only valid in a `switch` statement. PowerShell does not know about the C# `default` keyword and has no similar concept.

Comment:  I knew it was something stupid... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been pointed out in the comments. You can't just assign something called `Default` as your parameter's default value.

Since that enum doesn't have a "default" value, I'll suggest a different approach.

Don't use a default value for the parameter, then either use a conditional (bleh) or [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) (super cool) to handle that:

#### Conditional

```
function Log {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [string[]]$messages,

        [System.ConsoleColor]$color
    )

    if (($messages -eq $null) -or ($messages.Length -eq 0)) {
        $messages = @("")
    }

    foreach ($msg in $messages) {
        if ($color) {
            Write-Host $msg -ForegroundColor $color
        } else {
            Write-Host $msg
        }
        $msg | Out-File $logFile -Append
    }
}
```

#### Splatting

```
function Log {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [string[]]$messages,

        [System.ConsoleColor]$color
    )

    $params = @{}
    if ($color) {
        $params.ForegroundColor = $color
    }

    if (($messages -eq $null) -or ($messages.Length -eq 0)) {
        $messages = @("")
    }

    foreach ($msg in $messages) {
        Write-Host $msg @params

        $msg | Out-File $logFile -Append
    }
}
```